# woman: How do I just select the first manpage in PATH?

Tags: man, woman

`woman` keeps asking me which manpage I want:
[image]

I want it to just choose the first one in `woman-manpath`. I presume the shell's `man` command does something similar, since I'm never asked to choose.

Comment: > I presume the shell's man command does something similar, since I'm never asked to choose. ```
~$ man
What manual page do you want?
For example, try 'man man'.
```
I am using `bash`

Comment: The question is clearly analogous to `man zshall` (or maybe even `man zshall.1` or `man 1 zshall`).

Comment: The assumption being made is that the man pages are ordered.  I really doubt if man pages  are ordered.  What is the guarantee that what is `first` will NOT become `second` tomorrow.

Comment: It obviously depends on the code but, regardless of that, this answer does not seem relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The prompt comes from `woman-file-name` when `woman-file-name-all-completions` returns multiple possibilities.

Maybe you want something like this (untested):

```el
(define-advice woman-file-name-all-completions (:filter-return (completions) my-first)
  "Return only the first completion.

Advice for `woman-file-name-all-completions'.  Remove with:

\(advice-remove \\='woman-file-name-all-completions
               \\='woman-file-name-all-completions@my-first)"
  (list (car completions)))
```